# Wrong format error can't be handled with Try,Catch

Tags: ios, swift, try-catch, nsdateformatter

I am trying to format my timestamp, but when I get it in an other format I get an error for calendar.dateComponents. Now I am trying to throw an error if the timestamp is different. I always get the error `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` but it should throw the error.

```
 do{
        compMessage = try calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: outputStringTimestamp!)
        let minute = (String(format: "%02d", (compMessage?.minute!)!))
        let hour = (String(format: "%02d", (compMessage?.hour!)!))
        return "\(hour):\(minute)"
    }catch{
        return "0"

    }
```

How do I throw the error if the try is not working?

Comment: avoid force unwrapping and force casting and replace all ! with safe unwrap 

if let / guard let statements...

Comment: The code does not compile. The method `dateComponents:from:` does not `throw`. `Try - catch` can only be used for methods which are explicitly marked as `throw`.

Comment: `try` is for catching *errors.* `if/guard let` is for checking optionals.

Comment: @vadian so what would I use to ckeck this?

Comment: The  `minute` and `hour` properties cannot be `nil`, so `outputStringTimestamp` is `nil` and you have to check this with optional bindings and without `try - catch`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot catch errors thrown by force unwrapping of optional values or force casting. If you force unwrap an optional or force cast a value, you explicitly tell the compiler that the casting/unwrapping should always succeed and it can be done unsafely, so if it doesn't succeed, you get a runtime error, which is a programming error, since you used force casting/unwrapping.

Use safe optional unwrapping with `if let` or `guard let` to safely unwrap optionals.

Do-catch blocks can only be used to catch errors thrown by functions that are explicitly marked to `throw`.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers / comments already stated you can only throw from functions that are marked as `throwing`.

instead you can create a function like this:

```
func formatDate(_ date: Date) -> String {
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let components = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: date)
    return String(format: "%02d:%02d", hour!, minute!)
}

let someDate = Date()
let formattedDate = formatDate(someDate) // "13:05"
```

Comment: If `[.hour, .minute]` is specified `hour` and `minute` properties cannot be `nil`. The `guard` will never fail. The issue is related to `outputStringTimestamp`

Comment: @vadian So you would prefer forced unwrapping in this case?

Comment: Yes, it's one of the (few) cases where forced unwrapping is 100% safe (and is not *evil* per se ;-) )

Comment: @vadian you should use swiftlint ;)

Comment: @DominikBucher For what purpose? I don't miss anything. I'm one of the few people who reads the documentation and guides ;)